# heroku : The term 'heroku' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell, heroku

I installed heroku. I set the the bin folder path to environment variables. I have been trying to run command: `heroku -v` in my Visual Studio Code text editor. But I get the following error:

> heroku : The term 'heroku' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
>   was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + heroku -v
>   + ~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (heroku:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 9):

After correctly installing the Heroku CLI from the installer, the one more thing that needs to be done to run the Heroku commands in VS code terminal is to install the Heroku package from the npm. Use the following command for this:

```
npm install -g heroku
```

Now, to verify your CLI installation you can use the `heroku -v` or `heroku --version` command.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? I have trouble understanding why you'd need to install another copy of the CLI via `npm` after already installing it with the installer. More likely you just need to make sure your `PATH` is set correctly.

Comment: Hi @Chris, Its nearly been 2 years and I don’t exactly remember the source from where I got this solution. But the thing is that this worked for me as well as others who upvoted. Sometimes there are hacks which possibly don't have much explanation why that worked. I don't seem to understand why would you downvote a working solution.

Comment: Because it's not an answer to the question being asked. This installs a fully separate version of the Heroku CLI instead of fixing the problem with the one that's already installed via the installer. You say this is a required step, after having already used the installer. It certainly is _not_. The two things are unrelated. [Installing this way is explicitly discouraged by Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#install-with-npm): "It’s strongly recommended to use one of the other installation methods if possible."

Answer (score 2):

Just restart vs code and it will work. :)

Comment: Can you provide some more details about what you have tried, and what were the results?